# What should drush cvapi NotificationLog.retry sequential=1 system_log_id=XXX do?

Tags: api, contributions, authorize.net

Trying to re-run/retry some 'stuck'/"pending" notifications in the system log using:

drush cvapi NotificationLog.retry sequential=1 system_log_id=XXX

but that just produces an array with the JSON data in the log entry.

drush cvapi notification_log.retry id=748 used to do the trick.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that notification_retry api isn't core - its an extension :-)

Answer (score 2):

Eileen,thanks, duly noted that it's an extension, not in core. Thanks for writing the extension!

So to answer my own question -

drush cvapi NotificationLog.retry sequential=1 system_log_id=XXX

will retry/rerun system_log entries as the previous

drush cvapi notification_log.retry id=XXX

did, and I have no reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: Yep - that's correct & the output that you saw is expected - whether or not it succeeds I guess .

The extension is here https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.notificationlog

It currently only supports auhorize.net although the previous (fuzion repo) version also supported paypal, paybox & omnipay & there is not a lot of work to bring those back at some point

Comment: (I mention all that extra detail for other people who might read it Joe )

Comment: Eileen, thanks for all the extra detail - very useful