# Is it possible to do an IPN replay?

Tags: payment-processor, ipn

From CiviCRM 4.5 on, IPNs (recurring payment notifications from the payment processor) are recorded in `civicrm_system_log`.  Is there a way to replay these IPNs to CiviCRM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jon G, for Authorize, the answer is Yes, using Eileen's extension - see:

[What should drush cvapi NotificationLog.retry sequential=1 system_log_id=XXX do?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/4458/186)

and get the extension at:

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.notificationlog

Comment: Hey Jon G, is this the answer you were looking for, or at least part, or did I misunderstand the question? Those looking for Eileen's extension can go to https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.notificationlog

Comment: Just revisiting this old question - the additional comment is what answered things for me!

Comment: cool, glad to help