# Authorize.net ARB stopped working

Tags: recurring-contributions, authorize.net

Individual contributions on our site are working find but ARB transactions stopped working in March of 2016. Nothing has changed on our end as far as I know. I've upgraded to the latest Civicrm for Wordpress (v4.7.10), verified our silent post URL is correct at authorize.net, checked the API Access Key and Transaction Key are correct.

For recurring transactions, the initial transaction is processed fine by Authorize.net but an ARB subscription isn't configured and the transaction remains pending in CiviCRM.

I reached out to authorize.net and they stated they have no logs to assist troubleshooting and everything must be reviewed on our end.

Any ideas on where to check? We've got everything setup according to https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Authorize.net+Configuration

Only change I've done is to try the Akamai URLs rather than the older URLs.

Comment: Can you please update the question with your version of CiviCRM?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer definitively without knowing your version of CiviCRM.  However:

- If you're using CiviCRM 4.5+, IPN transactions (the silent post URL) are stored in `civicrm_system_log`.  You can also [replay them](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4505/is-it-possible-to-do-an-ipn-replay).
- You should search your web server logs (Apache/Nginx/etc.) for references to the IPN URL.  If you're not seeing them, then Authorize isn't talking to your server.  If they ARE there, check to see whether there was a 200 (success) response or another response (e.g. 404 error).
- Try visiting your IPN URL in your web browser.  Do you get a response along the lines of "The transaction has failed", or do you get something like your site's web page?  If the latter, you may have a broken redirect rule in your web server settings.

Comment: I'm running 4.7.10 for Wordpress.

In civicrm_system_log, I'm seeing "This transaction has been approved" both for non-recurring and recurring transactions.

I'll check the Apache logs

Visiting the IPN URL in a browser says The transaction has failed. Please review the log for more detail

Comment: @MichaelSchultheiss Are your missing ARB transactions present in `civicrm_system_log`?

Comment: Yes, the missing ARB transactions appear to be present in civicrm_system_log. I'm also seeing HTTP POSTs in the Apache access log from sm1e.visadpsmessage.com to the IPN URL with HTTP 200. From the logs it looks like everything should be working.

Comment: Hmm.  I've seen something similar where financial types were misconfigured, which caused IPNs to fail "silently" - but there was evidence in the CiviCRM logs.  Try replaying the IPNs per my link above, and see what shows up in the CiviCRM log?