# How to debug a recurring subscription that is not updating membership

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions

I've got a recurring membership that's not updating. I'm trying to figure out where/how to debug.

1. I can see that PayPal sent an IPN and got a 200 response from extern/ipn.php by looking in PayPal.
2. When I look at the recurring contribution in civi, I see the last updated date was Sept 3. (This IPN was a monthly recurring subscription for Oct 3). So it seems to not be registering it.
3. "Membership status processor (Hourly)" is enabled ("Process Offline Recurring Payments (Daily)" is not - but this isn't offline, right?)

How can I start to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `civicrm_system_log` contains records of all the IPNs that Civi gets.  See if it's present there.
- PayPal IPNs log quite a bit of data in the CiviCRM log (in the ConfigAndLog directory), even on success.  Find the log entry and look for errors.
- You can replay IPNs on CiviCRM 4.5+ using the "notificationlog" extension: [Is it possible to do an IPN replay?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4505/is-it-possible-to-do-an-ipn-replay)
- In some edge cases, it's worth checking your web server logs to correlate the call to `extern/ipn.php` with PayPal - I've seen a case where PayPal reported success on delivering the IPN - but it was to the wrong site.
- You can resend IPNs from PayPal for a certain number of days after the original: https://hq.palantetech.coop/projects/commons/wiki/PayPal#Resending-an-IPN

Comment: This definitely helped with the original question, which was how to debug and figure out what is failing. Ultimately what helped was replaying the extension and watching the ConfigAndLog/ folder for changes. I noticed it log "[info] Could not find payment processor for contribution record: 80498" - which led me down the rabbit hole to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16923 - so will pick it up from there. Thanks Jon G. !