# Authorize.net Recurring Payment not being updated

Tags: recurring-contributions, authorize.net

I have 2 or 3 recurring payments with Authorize.net that are not being updated in Civi.
Authorize.net shows that these recurring payments are being processed properly. 
CiviCRM shows the recurring payment as 'in progress' but the payment never shows up in CiviCRM.
For the most part, I have no issue with recurring payments, but I'd like to find out if there is a way to troubleshoot these few payments and get things working properly again.

Comment: Are all the details on the Authorize record complete and correct?  (the invoice ID, the customer ID)  And, what version of CiviCRM are you currently on?

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM records post parameters send by Authorize.net you can find it in civicrm_system_log table. You can also use api explorer to get the data using SystemLog  entity.

If you know the system log id than you can replay the ipn request to civicrm.

Ref: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4510/155

Comment: I installed the extension and retried the IPN but got this error
  "error_message": "Could not find an entry for x_invoice_num"
Not all my recurring payments have invoice numbers, why is it requiring it here?

Comment: all recurring payments should have invoice id

Comment: How can I fix it then? Is it enough to just add any random number to the subscription's invoice field in Authorize.net?

Comment: Figured it out. The Invoice ID is the CIviCRM contribution ID