# PayPalIPN: Could not find an entry for module

Tags: paypal, ipn

We get an error when PayPal is trying to confirm payment. In a nice letter Paypal tells us about the problem and shows the offending link, which is `.../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalIPN.php`. Opening that link gives the following backtrace:

```
CRM_Core_Exception: PayPalIPN: Could not find an entry for module in ...com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalIPN.php on line 315
Exception trace
#   Function    Location
0   CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalIPN->retrieve('module', 'String')    ...com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalIPN.php:315
1   CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalIPN->main()  ...com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php:780
2   CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl::handlePaymentNotification()    ...com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment.php:1379
3   CRM_Core_Payment::handlePaymentMethod('handlePaymentNot…', Array)   ...com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment.php:1281
4   CRM_Core_Payment::handleIPN()   ...com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:275
5   CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) ...com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:84
6   CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) ...com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:52
7   CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  ...com_civicrm/civicrm.php:96
8   civicrm_invoke()    ...com_civicrm/civicrm.php:11
9   require_once('/var/www/events/…')   ...libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:382
10  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent('/var/www/events/…') ...libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:357
11  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_civicrm')    ...libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:194
12  Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->dispatch()  ...libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:233
13  Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute() ...libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:195
14  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    ...index.php:49
15  {main}
```

Any ideas on what to do to debug? We're using Joomla 3.8.12 and Civi 5.4.1.

Update: I'm looking at the code there which says:

```
$component = $this->retrieve('module', 'String');
```

I'm suspecting that this means that it's trying to retrieve the module part of the calling URL (`/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalIPN.php`). So this URL is malformed for the IPN, right?

How does the `retrieve()` work?

UPDATE: When entering URL `.../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php` I get

```
The transaction has failed. Please review the log for more detail
```

and in the `civicrm_system_log` database table there is an entry, but with an empty "context" field, in which I suspect the transactionID etc. is supposed to be. This is natural in this case.

So I updated the IPN URL in the Paypal account to this and tried a resend of the latest failed IPN. It failed again, and even with the update URL I get a log entry in the `civicrm_system_log` table.

So it seems that Paypal has no "context" info for the transaction.

I've also checked that the URL does not redirect (using [Redirect Checker](http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php)), since [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/7482/354) seem to indicate that you loose POST data on redirect (which seems odd, but WTH and JIC).

Comment: Make sure the paypal is configured correctly. This error seems you aren't getting enough params from the ipn response.`retrieve` is only a function in Paypalipn.php which looks for the required input parameters and errors if it is not able to find them

Comment: What "paypal" are you referring to? The paypal payment processor (where there is very little that can be configured (URL:s to Paypal site and Paypal merchant account email), or the merchant info on the Paypal site (URL for the website and IPN URL which both seems to be placeholders according to the docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-standard/)?

Comment: And here's what Paypal seem to think it used as info: `{"module":"event","contactID":"12468","contributionID":661,"eventID":"93","participantID":2233}`

Comment: @thoni56 Just wondering did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue on my WordPress site, please let me know if you have any solution to this.
It was working fine till 15th November, now I am facing issue only for organization memberships, other PayPal contributions are working smoothly.

I am getting this in CiviCRM error logs-

Dec 07 17:43:14  [debug] PayPalIPN: Could not find an entry for module

Dec 07 17:43:14  [error] ipn_payment_callback_exception

Array
(

[context] => Array

(

[backtrace] => #0 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalIPN.php(296): CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalIPN->retrieve('module', 'String')

#1 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php(740): CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalIPN->main()

#2 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment.php(1594): CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl::handlePaymentNotification()

#3 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment.php(1485): CRM_Core_Payment::handlePaymentMethod('handlePaymentNo...', Array)

#4 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): CRM_Core_Payment::handleIPN()

#5 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)

#6 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)

#7 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1535): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)

#8 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(352): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()

#9 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))

#10 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)

#11 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)

#12 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(797): do_action_ref_array('wp', Array)

#13 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1332): WP->main('')

#14 /home/xyz/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()

#15 /home/xyz/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/xyz/...')

#16

{main}
[message] => PayPalIPN: Could not find an entry for module
)

)

Comment: StackExchange sites are not a discussion forum. It is expected that your post should be a potential answer to the question. I suggest that you create a new question describing your specific problem, what you have tried etc. Possibly referring to this question, if it is relevant or adds information that will help others provide possible answers to *your* question.