# Repeating Payments with Authorize.net Problem

Tags: recurring-contributions

I've set up repeating payments (CiviCRM 5.21 with Drupal 7.69) with Authorize.net for a client.

In Civi, the transaction hangs at "Pending".

At Auth.net, everything looks good, the initial payment has been processed with a date set for the next transaction.

Also note that one-off transactions from the site process perfectly with the transactions showing as "completed" in CiviCRM.

Not sure on how to troubleshoot this.

I thought that @Eileen's [notification log extention](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4458/what-should-drush-cvapi-notificationlog-retry-sequential-1-system-log-id-xxx-do/) might help. However, the system log table is empty.

I'm not sure what the next step is for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you! The issue was #1, no silent URL was set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make sure the Silent post URL is properly configured in Authorize.net.
Example: https://YOURSITE.COM/civicrm/payment/ipn/2 (the 2 needs to be replaced with your CiviCRM Payment Processor ID#)

2) It is possible that recurring payments are not processed instantly. It could be that recurring payments are processed in the middle of the night for example and therefore the payment will remain pending until it is processed.